# How to get the value of :ID: property of a org-contacts-entry in an org-capture-template?

Tags: org-capture, list, org-contacts

### Problem

I want to get the value of a property of a org-contacts-db entry:

```
\* Example Contact :MYTAG:   
:PROPERTIES:  
:ID: foobar  
:END:
```

With the function call `(org-contacts-filter "Example Contact" nil nil)` I get an alist of the contact "Example Contact" from the org-contacts-db, which looks something like

```
((#("Example Contact" 0 15 (fontified nil org-category "contacts"))
  #<marker at 14837 in contacts.org>
 (("CATEGORY" . "contacts")
  ("ID" . "foobar") …
```

In order to get the value corresponding to the key "ID" I tried `(cdr (assoc "ID" (org-contacts-filter "Example Contact" nil nil)))`, which only results in `nil`.

How do I get the value of the :ID: property?

### Context

I want to build a capture template for events which can only take place at certain locations. Those locations and their addresses are all managed with org-contacts. The entries for the locations of interest share tagged the same.
During the capture process I want to provide a list of locations, from which I can select the right one via the function my-capture-selection.

```
(defun my-capture-selection (list variable)  
  "Let the user choose between a pre-defined set of strings"  
  (make-local-variable variable)  
  (let ((selected-value (ido-completing-read "Select from list: " list)))  
    (set variable selected-value)  
    selected-value))
```

To create the list I can search my org-contacts-db for all entries with a certain tag.
`(org-contacts-filter nil "MYTAG" nil)`
The result is something like:

```
((#("NAME_1" … )) …
 ("ID" . "ORG_ID_1") …
 (#("NAME_2" … )) …
 ("ID" . "ORG_ID_2")
```

By calling `%(my-capture-selection (org-contacts-filter nil "MYTAG" nil) 'my-selection))` in my capture template, I see all contacts tagged "MYTAG", select one of them and save the selection to "my-selection".

In order to provide a link to the org-contact for the location, I want to get the "ID" property, which was created with org-id.
Since I already saved the name of the org-contacts-entry in "my-selection", I should be able to access any property of the entry.
With access to the value of "ID" I could build a link to the entry with `(concat "[[" …value of ID… "][" my-selection "]]")`

Comment: How about `org-id-get` -- "*Get the ID property of the entry at point-or-marker POM. ...*"?

Comment: Usually I won't start my capture process from within my org-contacts file. In order the get the ID of the correct contact I would have to visit my org-contacts file, search for the contacts heading, put a marker on it and invoke ´org-id-get´. Using the org-contacts-db seems to be the shorter and safer way to access a contacts properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have the answer.  The only problem is that the value returned by `org-contacts-filter` has several parts that need to be unpacked before you get to the assoc list.  A bit of experimenting gave me this, which seems to work:

```el
(cdr (assoc "ID"
            (nth 2 (car
                    (org-contacts-filter "Example Contact")))))
```

The second line is what I have added to your attempt.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. The code stays valid for getting the value of every other property present in the org-contacts-entry by exchanging "ID" with another property-key. Very helpful!